# Where is a clear, complete reference to iOS and Mac OS X networking errors like kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL?

Tags: ios, macos, ssl, network-programming, runtime-error

When debugging networking code in Xcode I often run into a sequence of errors such as the following:

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
```

None of my efforts to research those errors turn up a reference to them, so I can debug them sequentially without doing research for each individual one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most recent effort I know about is [osstatus.com](http://www.osstatus.com/).

The site identifies error [`-9802`](http://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-9802) as `errSSLFatalAlert` from `SecureTransport.h`.

Comment: This is very cool, but the site needs to be findable when people google the error messages.

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of searching I discovered that Apple's own reference pages don't link to the corresponding error numbers.  Then I was able to find the appropriate list of errors and the enum in the source code:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStreamConstants/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/CFStream_Error_Domain_Constants_CFHost_

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/secureTransportRef/

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libsecurity_ssl/libsecurity_ssl-36800/lib/SecureTransport.h

```
enum {
errSSLProtocol              = -9800,    /* SSL protocol error */
errSSLNegotiation           = -9801,    /* Cipher Suite negotiation failure */
errSSLFatalAlert            = -9802,    /* Fatal alert */
errSSLWouldBlock            = -9803,    /* I/O would block (not fatal) */
errSSLSessionNotFound       = -9804,    /* attempt to restore an unknown session */
errSSLClosedGraceful        = -9805,    /* connection closed gracefully */
errSSLClosedAbort           = -9806,    /* connection closed via error */
errSSLXCertChainInvalid     = -9807,    /* invalid certificate chain */
errSSLBadCert               = -9808,    /* bad certificate format */
errSSLCrypto                = -9809,    /* underlying cryptographic error */
errSSLInternal              = -9810,    /* Internal error */
errSSLModuleAttach          = -9811,    /* module attach failure */
errSSLUnknownRootCert       = -9812,    /* valid cert chain, untrusted root */
errSSLNoRootCert            = -9813,    /* cert chain not verified by root */
errSSLCertExpired           = -9814,    /* chain had an expired cert */
errSSLCertNotYetValid       = -9815,    /* chain had a cert not yet valid */
errSSLClosedNoNotify        = -9816,    /* server closed session with no notification */
errSSLBufferOverflow        = -9817,    /* insufficient buffer provided */
errSSLBadCipherSuite        = -9818,    /* bad SSLCipherSuite */

/* fatal errors detected by peer */
errSSLPeerUnexpectedMsg     = -9819,    /* unexpected message received */
errSSLPeerBadRecordMac      = -9820,    /* bad MAC */
errSSLPeerDecryptionFail    = -9821,    /* decryption failed */
errSSLPeerRecordOverflow    = -9822,    /* record overflow */
errSSLPeerDecompressFail    = -9823,    /* decompression failure */
errSSLPeerHandshakeFail     = -9824,    /* handshake failure */
errSSLPeerBadCert           = -9825,    /* misc. bad certificate */
errSSLPeerUnsupportedCert   = -9826,    /* bad unsupported cert format */
errSSLPeerCertRevoked       = -9827,    /* certificate revoked */
errSSLPeerCertExpired       = -9828,    /* certificate expired */
errSSLPeerCertUnknown       = -9829,    /* unknown certificate */
errSSLIllegalParam          = -9830,    /* illegal parameter */
errSSLPeerUnknownCA         = -9831,    /* unknown Cert Authority */
errSSLPeerAccessDenied      = -9832,    /* access denied */
errSSLPeerDecodeError       = -9833,    /* decoding error */
errSSLPeerDecryptError      = -9834,    /* decryption error */
errSSLPeerExportRestriction = -9835,    /* export restriction */
errSSLPeerProtocolVersion   = -9836,    /* bad protocol version */
errSSLPeerInsufficientSecurity = -9837, /* insufficient security */
errSSLPeerInternalError     = -9838,    /* internal error */
errSSLPeerUserCancelled     = -9839,    /* user canceled */
errSSLPeerNoRenegotiation   = -9840,    /* no renegotiation allowed */

/* non-fatal result codes */
errSSLServerAuthCompleted   = -9841,    /* server cert is valid, or was ignored if verification disabled */
errSSLClientCertRequested   = -9842,    /* server has requested a client cert */

/* more errors detected by us */
errSSLHostNameMismatch      = -9843,    /* peer host name mismatch */
errSSLConnectionRefused     = -9844,    /* peer dropped connection before responding */
errSSLDecryptionFail        = -9845,    /* decryption failure */
errSSLBadRecordMac          = -9846,    /* bad MAC */
errSSLRecordOverflow        = -9847,    /* record overflow */
errSSLBadConfiguration      = -9848,    /* configuration error */
errSSLLast                  = -9849     /* end of range, to be deleted */
};
```

TL;DR There are no web pages (except this one now) that have the word kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL together with the error numbers, not even Apple reference pages.

Comment: Somebody should make a function that turns these error codes into their corresponding human-readable description strings, and post it as a gist.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple good error code web sites:

2357 [List Of Mac OS X Error Codes](http://krypted.com/commands/comprehensive-list-of-mac-os-x-error-codes/) Also Commands, Guides and Tools
897 [Macintosh Error Codes](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/user/lenzo/html/mac_errors.html)

But unfortunately neither of these have information on -9802.

Suggestion: [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com)